# is it possible to send uploaded file from angularjs to spring controller but by formbean

Tags: angularjs, spring

I have form having text field and file type. I want to send this to controller using form bean. here is my code.following is my js file. from where I'm sending multipart file.

```
myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function (file, uploadUrl, uploadform) {
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);
        fd.append("jsondata", JSON.stringify(uploadform));
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
                .success(function () {
                })
                .error(function () {
                });
    }
}]);

myApp.controller('myFileUpload', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function ($scope, fileUpload) {

    $scope.uploadFile = function () {
        var file = $scope.myFile;
        $scope.uploadform = {};
        var uploadUrl = "navigation/uploadexcel";
        fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl, $scope.uploadform);
    };

}]);
```

and my controller is..I want to map multipart file and textbox value into firmbean first and from that I want to get my file for further process.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadexcel", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
String upload(@RequestBody EmployeeFormBean fb) {
    String res = null;
    try {
        MultipartFile f = fb.getFile();
        System.out.println("-->"+ f.getOriginalFilename());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return res;
}
```

my jsp code is as following

```
<div style="background-color: blanchedalmond">
    <div ng-controller = "myFileUpload">
        <input type="file" file-model="myFile"/>
        <input type="text" name="template" ng-model="uploadform.templateName"/>
        <button ng-click="uploadFile()">upload me</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

but m getting error as follow...

```
415 Unsupported Media Type
    59ms    
angular...DF52B9C (line 103)
HeadersPostResponseHTMLCookies
"NetworkError: 415 Unsupported Media Type -         http://localhost:8080/crmdemo1/navigation/uploadexcel"
```

how to resolve this issue. I dont want to do it by @resuestparam("file")
is it possible to do this using formbean.. and if yes please tell me how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in the content type of your request, try to add `headers = "content-type=multipart/*" , consumes = "application/json"` to @RequestMapping. Beside that (in your service fileUpload) change  the `headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}` to `headers: {'Content-Type': application/json}`. Hope this will help you

Comment: try to remove `@RequestBody`